# Hibernate not letting me add an entity with a Derby Database that has an auto-gen Identity PK

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, glassfish, hibernate-annotations

I have a Derby Database Table with the following fields.  The database ID fields automatically generates and increments.

```
create table "Yaya".SERVICELOG
(
ID INTEGER default AUTOINCREMENT: start 1 increment 1 not null primary key,
TXTIME TIMESTAMP,
EVENTLEVEL INTEGER,
EVENTTYPE VARCHAR(255),
DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(4096)
)
```

Using NetBeans I am trying to use Hibernate as an ORM.  I have used Linq2SQL and EF before...This is becoming traumatic.

Here is my generated POJO, I believe the annotations are correct.

```
// Generated Sep 19, 2014 12:26:20 PM by Hibernate Tools 4.3.1


import java.util.Date;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Servicelog generated by hbm2java
 */
public class Servicelog  implements java.io.Serializable {

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 private int id;
 private Date txtime;
 private Integer eventlevel;
 private String eventtype;
 private String description;

public Servicelog() {
}


public Servicelog(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Servicelog(int id, Date txtime, Integer eventlevel, String eventtype, String description) {
   this.id = id;
   this.txtime = txtime;
   this.eventlevel = eventlevel;
   this.eventtype = eventtype;
   this.description = description;
}

public int getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public Date getTxtime() {
    return this.txtime;
}

public void setTxtime(Date txtime) {
    this.txtime = txtime;
}
public Integer getEventlevel() {
    return this.eventlevel;
}

public void setEventlevel(Integer eventlevel) {
    this.eventlevel = eventlevel;
}
public String getEventtype() {
    return this.eventtype;
}

public void setEventtype(String eventtype) {
    this.eventtype = eventtype;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return this.description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
}
```

Here is my code for the insert.

```
    Session session = StartupBean.sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Servicelog sl = new Servicelog();
    sl.setDescription("IN IT TO WIN IT");
    session.save(sl);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

It bombs out with the following in the glassfish server console on the `session.getTransaction().commit();`

> Info:   HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null WARN:   HHH000402:
>   Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
>   Info:   HHH000401: using driver [org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver]
>   at URL [jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/yayadb] Info:   HHH000046:
>   Connection properties: {user=yayaadmin, password=****} Info:
>   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false Info:   HHH000115: Hibernate
>   connection pool size: 20 (min=1) Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect:
>   org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect WARN:   HHH000430: The DerbyDialect
>   dialect has been deprecated; use one of the version-specific dialects
>   instead Info:   HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct
>   JDBC transactions) Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
>   Info:   Loading application [yaya] at [/yaya] Info:   yaya was
>   successfully deployed in 6,323 milliseconds.
>
> WARN:   SQL Error: -1, SQLState: 42Z23
>
> ERROR:   Attempt to modify an identity column 'ID'.
>
> Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[DbTest]: Servlet.service() for servlet
>   DbTest threw exception org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException:
>   could not prepare statement   at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:80)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:196)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:96)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.buildBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:152)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl.getBatchStatement(AbstractBatchImpl.java:141)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3102)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3587)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:103)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:453)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:345)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1218)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:421)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
>     at com.ya.ya.zzzyaya.DbTest.processRequest(DbTest.java:97)  at
>   com.ya.ya.zzzyaya.DbTest.doGet(DbTest.java:116)   at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)  at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
>     at
>   org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>
> Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Attempt to modify an
>   identity column 'ID'.
>
> at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$1.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:103)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
>     ... 45 more Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException:
>   Attempt to modify an identity column 'ID'.    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeSqlca(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePrepareError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parsePRPSQLSTTreply(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatement.readPrepareDescribeOutput_(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.readPrepareDescribeOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowPrepareDescribeInputOutput(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.derby.client.am.Connection.prepareStatementX(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 48 more

I've been at it for a few hours and I have no idea how to proceed.  What do I have to change in hibernate so it is smart enough to not fling in a primary key?

Comment: define `id` as `Integer` or `Long`.

Comment: @Rp-that helped!  Now I am getting this error:
org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): com.yaya.yyy.Servicelog
 at org.hibernate.id.Assigned.generate(Assigned.java:52)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, I figured it out, thanks in part to Rp-'s comment

```
private int id;
```

had to be changed to

```
private Integer id;
```

And in the Servicelog.hbm.xml

```
    <id name="id" type="int">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
```

to

```
    <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
        <column name="ID" />
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
```

Comment: Does anyone know the relationship between the code annotation @GeneratedValue and the <generator class=""> attribute in the XML ?

Comment: Both are equivalents. We use either of them based on if we are using annotations or hbms for the OR mappings. `GenerationType.IDENTITY` is equal to `<generator class="identity" />`. In general `IDENTITY` is dependent of underlying database. It wont support all the databases. I doubt that `Derby` can not support `identity`, but im not sure though. If you define `GenerationType.ASSIGNED`, you should assign the key before you save.

Comment: How do I designate whether to use annotations or the hbms xml file ?  I would prefer to use annotations.

Comment: Then you should stick only with annotations, its bad idea to combine both hbms and annotations. You need to use `AnnotationConfiguration.congiure()` while configuring your `SessionFactory`. You will find better help and tutorial online.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;
```

Comment: Adding comments / explanations to your code would make your answer even better.

Comment: @Moni - Nah, I tried all of the GenerationType s, did not seem to have any impact.